# Mousse au Chocolat without cacao - resembling the taste of cacao / cocoa

Tags: flavor, cocoa

How to make Mousse au Chocolat (normally consisting of eggs, cream, cacao powder, sugar, possibly some butter and vanilla) *without* any cacao or cocoa powder.
It should still taste like cacao and a nutty or caramel-like flavor is welcome too

Comment: I don’t know if there’s anything that might help to modify carob better (maybe espresso powder?  Lots of recipes says it enhances chocolate flavors). Foodsubs recommends reducing the temperature when baking it: https://foodsubs.com/ingredients/cocoa

Comment: Hey, it's pretty hard to take questions on SA that ask for a listing of "everything", becuase there's never any way to know that the list is complete, and you end up with multiple, overlapping, but not identical, lists in the answers.  Can you change this question to ask for -- for example -- cacao substitutions for a particular purpose?  or ones that can be combined?

Comment: Thats a great idea. Thanks @Joe
Got it, that's true. I just wanted to point out that everything that may come to your mind, is what I am looking for. Not that I want to know everything in existence. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I think you misunderstood FuzzyChef. The problem is not with the single word "anything", the problem is what an answer could be. We don't take questions which produce an answer that is a list of things. A substitution question we can take would look like "I have this recipe that contains cocoa powder (here you give the recipe). Which possible substitute would fit into this recipe while producing a taste and texture as close as possible to the original."

Comment: Hm. Well then, I don't get it. It's silly to ask this way. I am interested in what ingredients might taste like cacao, not how to redesign one specific recipe.
I see the difficulty, though, in that you couldn't choose one right answer at the end. Probably I would write an answer at the end, summarizing all options.
Asking for a specific recipe is simply wrong. You should change the rules. Anyway, I will just do it.

Comment: @Sebastian please don't write such a summarizing answer - the rules were made specifically to prevent this kind of "all options" answers from being written. I get that what you want to have is a list; this kind of answer breaks our system in different ways and so is not allowed, neither are questions leading to it. So your current question would also have to be edited such that your question for "different things" is removed. Seeing that the new question won't produce what you wanted to know, do you want us to do the editing and reopen, or do you want it to stay closed?

Comment: Yah, I was about to vote to reopen, but if the question as written isn't what the OP actually wants to know, why bother?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I Appreciate your help in reopening it. It is indeed what I want to know. Knowing it for one recipe, sure helps in all others too. Just thought it was clearer when keeping it generell. Please have a look at whether the question is okay now

Comment: @Sebastian yes, it looks OK now - that was implied in the reopening :) Thank you for working with us and editing.